# Wrong result after dividing signed integer

Tags: assembly, x86, division

Basic question:

I wrote the following block of code:

```
DATASEG

Result db ?
Modulo db ?

var3 db -9
var4 db 2


CODESEG

start:

    mov ah, 0
    mov al, [var3]
    mov bl, [var4]
    div bl
    mov [Result], al
    mov [Modulo], ah
```

I get wrong result for -9/2. 
The result I get is "7B", seems that it treats "F7" as 247.

How can I get this done correctly while still defining var3 as a databyte (db)?

Or, is there any other way?

Thanks for answers

Comment: See [manual page for `DIV`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_72.html). it says *unsigned divide*.

Comment: Assembly language coder hint:   If an instruction doesn't seem to do what you expect, go read the instruction set reference *carefully*.   The instruction usually does what it is designed to do, and the problem is in your understanding of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `idiv` to perform a signed division.

`div` will not correctly process the negative number in *var3*

```
mov al, [var3]
cbw
idiv byte ptr [var4]
```

From your comments I see that you don't like the `cbw` instruction and that you don't want to use the shortest code for the division instruction. You can always code it like:

```
mov   al, [var3]
mov   ah, FFh      ;Only if you 'know' var3 has a negative value!
mov   bl, [var4]
idiv   bl
mov   [Result], al
mov   [Modulo], ah
```

Alternatively and still avoiding `cbw`:

```
movsx ax, byte ptr [var3]
mov   bl, [var4]
idiv   bl
mov   [Result], al
mov   [Modulo], ah
```

Comment: I replaced it with "idiv", i get the same result, '01' in ah and '7B' in al

Comment: is there anyway doing this not by using the 'cbw' command? and by that only 'al' will consist of 'F7'?

Comment: Even with `cbw` will AL=F7h. `cbw` will just put FFh in AH. If you want then just replace `cbw` with `mov ah,FFh`

Comment: so how do this solution works? because of "byte ptr"? my code with the change to idiv did not work.. plus, I already defined [var4] as a databyte.

Comment: Hang on, don't you still need `idiv`, not `div`, after sign-extending `var3` into `ax`?  So `movsz ax, byte ptr [var3] / idiv byte ptr [var4]` should do the trick.  Or load it into bl first if you like.  And @tilikompowaa: you need `byte ptr` because labels don't have an associated size.  You could do a 32bit load of 4 consecutive bytes, if you wanted, even if each byte had its own label.  Don't think of labels as "variables", just think of them as `void*`, and it's up to you to specify the right operand size when loading/storing, if it's not implicit from the register size.

Comment: @PeterCordes Your absolutely right. I forgot to change `div` into `idiv` after copying/pasting the OP's code. I edited the answer.